# Could not log history/error message even though sysadmin?

Tags: sql-server

I have a job setup that copies transaction logs for log shipping purposes.

It seems to be working, I think, but I can't verify that because of the following error:

> 2021-08-22 21:00:00.86 Starting transaction log copy. Secondary ID:
> 'c29f....' 2021-08-22 21:00:00.87 Error: Could not log history/error
> message.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping) 2021-08-22
> 21:00:00.87 Error: Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role can
> perform this operation.(.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

I checked permissions, and clearly I'm `sysadmin`.

So why is it complaining?

[image: sysadmin]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by reverting the SQL Server service and agent services logon creds from my local account to the default NT service accounts per [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/298397/237400) post.

Strange since my AzureAD logon account is part of sysadmin...